# Why does Spotlight not return the correct result?

Tags: osx-lion, search, spotlight

[image]

I dont know if the search features on most operating system is bogus or I am getting it wrong.

I am looking for a particular file where css property is set like

```
left:-59px;
```

I perform search on current folder and type `-59px`. It give me a *bunch* of files. The file names does not contain `-59` like in auction_rate.html and when I open the file and search for `-59px`, it says "nothing found".

So my question is, is that search feature really bogus or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, any typical search engine takes the minus/hyphen as the `NOT` operator, therefore you're searching for anything *not* containing what you entered.

In fact, Spotlight supports boolean queries. If you type `foo bar`, it'll search for `foo AND bar`. If you type `foo | bar`, it'll search for `foo OR bar`. And if you type `-59px;`, it'll search for `NOT 59px;`.

To get exactly what you entered, just search for `left:-59px;`.

Comment: so it search the file contents by default?

Comment: And the title! You can so custom searches of course.

Comment: also I could have used "-59x" in quotes